# Canvas showing zoomed images for correct dimension

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, android-webview

Canvas was showing the images correctly but with `chrome 62` or some other reason I am seeing a problem that my images are not getting loaded properly.

For example, my previous working canvas dimension was this:

```
<canvas width="587" height="900"></canvas>
```

And my resources/images that were loaded in the canvas were of the dimension of `587*900` only. But in some devices suddenly I am seeing an image like this:

[image]

The above image is the zoomed version for the image below. Now if I change the canvas dimension to the following:

```
<canvas width="600" height="900"></canvas>
```

I get the correct output as this:

[image]

Now, the problem being this was not happening before and it was working properly. Even now for the older dimension it is working properly but only in some Android devices this error is seen.

So, I want to know the reason why this is happening, is it because of some Chrome update or is it some other reason, as the image seen in second avatar all are of size `587*900`.

Directive part:

```
angular.module('xpresso')
    .directive('avatarcanvas', function () {        
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            template:  '<div>\
                <canvas width="600" height="900"  style="display:none;"></canvas>\
                <img class="canvas-image">\
                </div>',
            scope: {
                customizable: '@' ,
                source: '@',
                uicolor: '@',
                fromDirectiveFn: '=method'
            },
            link: function($scope, element, attr) {
                //1. Configure Canvas.
                var canvas = element[0].children[0];
                var image = element[0].children[1];
                //fitToContainer(canvas);

                //2. Observers for color and image URL
                attr.$observe('source', function(imageURL) {
                    if(imageURL) {
                        var imageObj = new Image();
                        imageObj.onload = function() {
                            $scope.fromDirectiveFn();
                            clearCanvas(canvas);

                            if ($scope.fillColor == "0") { //No color
                                drawImageWithNoColor(canvas, imageObj);
                                image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                            } else { //Apply color
                                if($scope.name == 'Eye' || $scope.name == 'BroShapes' || $scope.name=="MouthShapes") {
                                    conditionalReplace('0000FF', canvas, imageObj, $scope.fillColor);
                                } else {
                                    drawImage(canvas,
                                    imageObj,
                                    $scope.fillColor);
                                }

                                image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                            }

                            $scope.imageReference = imageObj;
                        };

                        imageObj.src = imageURL;
                    }
                });

                attr.$observe('uicolor', function(color) {
                    $scope.fillColor = color;
                    if ($scope.imageReference != undefined) {
                        clearCanvas(canvas);
                        if ($scope.name == 'Eye' || $scope.name == 'BroShapes' || $scope.name == "MouthShapes") {
                            conditionalReplace('0000FF', canvas, $scope.imageReference, $scope.fillColor);
                        } else {
                            drawImage(canvas,
                            $scope.imageReference,
                            $scope.fillColor);
                        }

                        image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    }
                });

                //Observe for type.
                attr.$observe('name', function(name) {
                    $scope.name = name;
                });
            }
        }
```

Few functions I have not added, which are being called from the above code.

Comment: What code is rendering the image to your canvas?

Comment: @Cerbrus Edited the question.